# "Could not find a part of the path error on Publish" Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Anyone came accross this error in visual studio. when I Publish my project to IIS. Im getting some errors  and checked the files on the said path and those files exists. I've tried several steps modifiying my registry 'accept long path' but didn't worked. I just moved my entire project from my local drive C: to  G: and when I publish my project I encounter this error

sample error
Could not copy "G:\Shared drives\Information Technology\Employee Folders\Application Development\ASP.net\Exposure Tracker\Exposure Tracker Files\ExposureTracker\wwwroot\Atlantis Theme\js\plugin\jqvmap\maps\continents\jquery.vmap.australia.js" to "G:\Shared drives\Information Technology\Employee Folders\Application Development\ASP.net\Exposure Tracker\Exposure Tracker Files\ExposureTracker\obj\Release\net6.0\PubTmp\Out\wwwroot\Atlantis Theme\js\plugin\jqvmap\maps\continents\jquery.vmap.australia.js". Beginning retry 8 in 1000ms. Could not find a part of the path 'G:\Shared drives\Information Technology\Employee Folders\Application Development\ASP.net\Exposure Tracker\Exposure Tracker Files\ExposureTracker\obj\Release\net6.0\PubTmp\Out\wwwroot\Atlantis Theme\js\plugin\jqvmap\maps\continents\jquery.vmap.australia.js'.

Comment: The path length that vs can accept is limited, what is the reason why you need to use such a long path？ Have you tried using short paths?

Comment: We've got a google drive which is the G: where i used to saved my project than saving it to a C: local drive. no worries i just used the C: drive which is working fine. hehe